# What does "In-universe" mean?

Tags: discussion, terminology

I am new to this discussion and trying to wrap my head around the terms I see on this site. Certainly, "In-universe" comes up all the time.

Does it mean in a certain version of a story. For example, the difference between the story in Star Trek 2009 and Star Trek?

Answer (score 15):

"In-universe" means that it is something valid or correct **from the point of view of fictional story (or a universe of stories, e.g. Harry Potter)**

This is opposite of "out of universe", aka "outside the 4th wall" - things which are true in our real world.

A good example of in-universe vs. out-of-universe information is:

**Q:** Why did this character on fiction TV show die?

**A: (in-universe)**: Because this other character was a son of a person the first character killed, and they wanted revenge.

**A: (out-of-universe)**: Because the character was played by an actor who was demanding a salary too high for the budget.