# What is the meaning by "Out of Universe"?

Tags: discussion, canon

I've seen an answer from my questions like [Why didn't McGonagall send only Parkinson to the dungeons?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/159873/why-didnt-mcgonagall-send-only-parkinson-to-the-dungeons)

What I'm referring to is

> Well, the movies are nonsense, but putting that to one side... **Out of universe** it's a sarcastic joke and that may even be part of it in universe as well. A bit of humour to relieve the tension before the battle. I don't think, in-universe, the Slytherins were ever actually taken to the dungeons, McGonagall was clearly being snarky and sarcastic.

But I've seen questions mentioning "Out of Universe" from this website.  I researched for this meaning but I don't understand it. So please help me. =)

Comment: Good question! It's already been covered here though; I've closed as a duplicate of [these](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1541/31394) two [questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7648/31394) about the complementary term "in-universe". I believe reading their answers should tell you all you need to know.